# change unit programmatically in autocad

Tags: wpf, autocad

I'm using sendcommand to draw various shapes in autocad.

the problem is my application (wpf) uses pixel units while autocad uses inches by default.

how can I change autocad units to pixel programmatically?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AutoCAD units represent "real world" distances, and pixels represent "on screen" distances. You need to decide what real world distance a pixel should equate to inside your dwg.

If you want the exact same size on screen you need to take into account zoom settings and so-on, and I wouldn't hold much hope of getting it all that accurate.

I would also avoid imperial measurements like the plague, especially for what you're doing. Set your AutoCAD to work with metric units unless you really must use imperial.

It seems a pretty trivial choice so I'd go for a very "linear" ratio for pixel to unit, like 1:1 or 1:100 and then play with the zoom.

Answer (score 4):

The following chunk of code will help you.

```
Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database.Insunits=UnitsValue.Feet;
```